# SQLite script to MongoDB

Tags: sql, mongodb, translate, converters

I'm a newbie on MongoDB. And I need help. I have a small project with SQLite (7 tables and 1 view). And I need to make this project on MongoDB, I'm using Studio 3T, I'm already migrate SQLite tables to MongoDB collections, but now I need to make (VIEW/TEST) for test this project. Please help how to write this SQL script with MongoDB.
**SQLITE:**

[image]

**MongoDB:**

[image]

SQLIte script I want to make with MongoDB:

```
CREATE VIEW rezultatas AS
    SELECT p.pavadinimas AS detales_pavadinimas,
        SUM(d.pagamintas_kiekis) AS pagamintas_kiekis,
        SUM(z.gamybos_islaidos) AS vidutine_kaina,
        STRFTIME('%m', d.pagaminimo_data) AS menuo,
        STRFTIME('%Y', d.pagaminimo_data) AS metai
    FROM detales d,
         zinynas z,
         produktas p
   WHERE (z.detale_id = p._id_) AND
         (d.detale_id = z.detale_id) AND
         (d.pagaminimo_data >= z.data_nuo) AND
        NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                    FROM zinynas
                  WHERE (d.detale_id = detale_id) AND
                        (d.pagaminimo_data >= data_nuo) AND
                        (z.data_nuo < data_nuo)
        )
   GROUP BY p.pavadinimas,
            STRFTIME('%m', d.pagaminimo_data),
            STRFTIME('%Y', d.pagaminimo_data)
```

Comment: MongoDB is not a relational database. Most likely, you won't be able to clone the db schema that relies on joins etc.

Comment: I personally thing its easily doable, you just need to convert this into a Mongo pipeline if you provide the schemes it would make it easier for me to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I had to guess some things due to the lack of schemes but the basic layout should work.

We're going to use [$createView](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createView/) with these parameters as input:

`db.createView('rezultatas', 'produktas', pipeline)`

Meaning our pipeline creating the view starts with the `produktas` collection.

The pipeline to use:

```
[
    { // match the documents from the zinyas collection.
        $lookup:
            {
                from: "zinynas",
                let: { produktas_id: "$_id" }, // i'm guessing its _id
                pipeline: [
                    { $match:
                            { $expr: { $eq: [ "$detale_id",  "$$produktas_id" ] }}
                    },
                ],
                as: "z"
            }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$z"
    },
    {  // match the documents from the detales collection. only keep the one with maximum data_nuo value.
        $lookup:
            {
                from: "detales",
                let: { z_detale_id: "$z.detale_id", z_data_nuo: "$z.data_nuo" },
                pipeline: [
                    { $match:
                            {
                                $and: [
                                    { $expr: { $eq: [ "$detale_id",  "$$z_detale_id" ] }},
                                    { $expr: { $gte: [ "$pagaminimo_data", "$$z_data_nuo"]}}
                                ]
                            }
                    },
                    {
                        $sort: {
                            data_nuo: -1
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $limit: 1
                    }
                ],
                as: "d"
            }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$d"
    },
    {  // end up saving the fields we want.
        $group: {
            _id: { pavadinimas : "$pavadinimas", month: {$month: "$d.pagaminimo_data"}, year: {$year: "$d.pagaminimo_data"}},
            pagamintas_kiekis: {$sum: "$d.pagamintas_kiekis"},
            vidutine_kaina: {$sum: "$z.gamybos_islaidos"},
            month: {$first: {$month: "$d.pagaminimo_data"}},
            year: {$first: {$year: "$d.pagaminimo_data"}},
            detales_pavadinimas: {$first: "$pavadinimas"}
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: 2020-01-07T16:39:15.449+0200 E QUERY    [js] ReferenceError: pipeline is not defined :

@(shell):1:1 I get this when i try create pipeline

Comment: what do you mean create pipeline? just paste the pipeline i posted.

Comment: And i get this error Failed to execute script.

Error:
ReferenceError: pipeline is not defined 
Details:
@(shell):1:1

Comment: `pipeline` is an undefined parameter - where i wrote pipeline it means the array with all the Mongo aggregation stages. i wrote it this way for read-ability